# how to return or a list of items of care is based on several classes

Tags: c++, class, pointers

In my function '`func`' i want to create an object Menu who returns a breakfast with lemon and coffee. '`func`' return a list of menu

When I try to display the menu for a breakfast that contains only lemon or only coffee it is displayed correctly. For example:

```
c.push_back(make_unique<Breakfast>("eggs", 10));
```

but when i try to display a menu that also contains lemon and coffee it shows me error in main

this is the program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Menu {
private:
    int price;
public:
    Menu(int p = 0) : price{ p } {}
    virtual string description() = 0;
    virtual int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    virtual ~Menu() {}
};
class WithLemon : public Menu {
private:
    Menu* meniu;

public:
    
    WithLemon(Menu* n) :
        meniu{ n } {}
    string description() override {
        return meniu->description() + " with lemon ";
    }
    int getPrice() override {
        return meniu->getPrice() + 4;
    }
};

class WithCoffee : public Menu {
private:
    Menu* meniu;
public:
    WithCoffee(Menu* n) :
        meniu{ n } {
    }
    string description() override {
        return meniu->description() + " with coffee ";
    }
    int getPrice() override {
        return meniu->getPrice() + 5;
    }
};

class Breakfast : public Menu {
private:
    string name;
public:
    Breakfast(string n, int p) :
        name{ n }, Menu{ p }  {
    }
    string description() override {
        return name;
    }
};
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Menu>>  func(void)
{
    std::vector <std::unique_ptr<Menu> > c;
    
    
    Breakfast a{ "breakfast eggs", 10 };
    WithCoffee breakfast_with_coffee{ &a };
    Menu* breakfast_with_coffee_and_lemon = new WithLemon{ &breakfast_with_coffee };
    //cout << breakfast_with_coffee_and_lemon->description() << " " << breakfast_with_coffee_and_lemon->getPrice();// print ----> breakfast eggs with coffee  with lemon  19
    
    c.push_back(make_unique<WithLemon>(&breakfast_with_coffee));
    return c;
}
int main() {

    std::vector < std::unique_ptr<Menu> > lista = func();
    for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {
        cout << lista[i]->description() << " " << lista[i]->getPrice() << endl; //error read memory access
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You construct an instance of `WithLemon` and give it a pointer to a local variable. When `func` returns, that local variable is destroyed, leaving `WithLemon` instance holding a dangling pointer. Any attempt to use that pointer then exhibits undefined behavior, by way of accessing an object after its lifetime has ended. You need to think carefully about the lifetime of various objects you create, to make sure they actually still exist when you attempt to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't take a pointer to automatic memory, store it in a smart pointer and leave the function. After you leave the function the automatic memory is freed and the smart pointer contains a dangling pointer. The simplest way to avoid this problem and other problems with memory leaks is to use smart pointers for all variables:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Menu {
private:
    int price;
public:
    Menu(int p = 0) : price{ p } {}
    virtual std::string description() = 0;
    virtual int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    virtual ~Menu() = default;
};

class WithLemon : public Menu {
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Menu> meniu;

public:
    WithLemon(Menu* n) : meniu{ n } {}
    std::string description() override {
        return meniu->description() + " with lemon ";
    }
    int getPrice() override {
        return meniu->getPrice() + 4;
    }
};

class WithCoffee : public Menu {
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Menu> meniu;
public:
    WithCoffee(Menu* n) :
        meniu{ n } {
    }
    std::string description() override {
        return meniu->description() + " with coffee ";
    }
    int getPrice() override {
        return meniu->getPrice() + 5;
    }
};

class Breakfast : public Menu {
private:
    std::string name;
public:
    Breakfast(std::string n, int p) : Menu{ p }, name{ n }  {}
    std::string description() override {
        return name;
    }
};

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Menu>>  func(void) {
    std::vector <std::unique_ptr<Menu> > c;
    
    auto a = std::make_unique<Breakfast>("breakfast eggs", 10);
    auto breakfast_with_coffee = std::make_unique<WithCoffee>(a.release());
    //Menu* breakfast_with_coffee_and_lemon = new WithLemon{ breakfast_with_coffee };
    //std::cout << breakfast_with_coffee_and_lemon->description() << " " << breakfast_with_coffee_and_lemon->getPrice();// print ----> breakfast eggs with coffee  with lemon  19
    
    c.push_back(std::make_unique<WithLemon>(breakfast_with_coffee.release()));
    return c;
}

int main() {

    std::vector < std::unique_ptr<Menu> > lista = func();
    for (const auto &i : lista) {
        std::cout << i->description() << " " << i->getPrice() << std::endl; //error read memory access
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Avoid raw `new` and `delete`. Avoid pointers to automatic memory.